# UNION operator does not return any results in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am working in SQLite and trying to make a query to return a table containing top five jobs in each of four regions (coastal, alpine, regional and metro) based on their respective incomes.
Each SELECT statement for a specific region returns correct result however, appending these separate results in one table using UNION does not return any table where UNION is underlined in red:

```
-- 
select  job,
--          income as "Top_incomes",
            1 as "income",
           region.name
from customers
JOIN customer_region on customers.id = customer_region.customer_id
JOIN region on region.id = customer_region.region_id
where region.name =  "regional"
ORDER by income DESC limit 5;
UNION
select  job,
--          income as "Top_incomes",
            2 as "income",
           region.name
from customers
JOIN customer_region on customers.id = customer_region.customer_id
JOIN region on region.id = customer_region.region_id
where region.name = "coastal"
ORDER by income DESC limit 5
```

Although the number of columns per each statement is 3 and they all have the same column names for each statement, I am not sure why UNION does not return any result as a single table. Is there any wrong query syntax here? Thanks

```
-- 
select  job,
--          income as "Top_incomes",
            1 as "income",
           region.name
from customers
JOIN customer_region on customers.id = customer_region.customer_id
JOIN region on region.id = customer_region.region_id
where region.name =  "regional"
ORDER by income DESC limit 5;
UNION
select  job,
--          income as "Top_incomes",
            2 as "income",
           region.name
from customers
JOIN customer_region on customers.id = customer_region.customer_id
JOIN region on region.id = customer_region.region_id
where region.name = "coastal"
ORDER by income DESC limit 5
```

I was expecting to get a single table containing results from each SELECT statement: 5 top-income jobs from the 'regional' region followed by the 5 top-income jobs from the 'coastal' region. I did not get any results back.

Comment: there is a syntax error. You have a semicolon after the "first" query, which ends the statement. I don't think you can use order by except at the end of the UNION'ed queries, so that another syntax error I think.

Comment: Please explain what `ORDER by income` is supposed to be doing.  Note that in both subqueries `income` always has the same value.

Comment: Hi Tim, ORDER BY income DESC sorts the income results from the most to the least, obviously. I have tried two SELECT queries separately and they returned different incomes. The issue is that these two SELECT queries do not stick together in a single table.

Comment: Hi topsail, the semicolon is not the cause of issue. In fact, when I do not place semicolon at the end of first query, all of my queries get underlined in red ; however, when I place semicolon there, only UNION gets underlined. In either case, query does not return anything. By the way, I don't intend to use ORDER BY at the end of UNION'ed queries because this is not what I am aiming at outputting.

Answer (score 1):

In a union query, the outermost `ORDER BY` clause applies to the entire query, not any individual select.  You may use the following syntax:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT job,
           income AS Top_incomes,
           1 AS income,
           r.name
   FROM customers c
   INNER JOIN customer_region rc ON c.id = cr.customer_id
   INNER JOIN region r ON r.id = cr.region_id
   WHERE r.name = 'regional'
   ORDER BY income DESC
   LIMIT 5
)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT job,
           income,
           2,
           r.name
    FROM customers c
    INNER JOIN customer_region cr ON c.id = cr.customer_id
    INNER JOIN region r ON r.id = cr.region_id
    WHERE r.name = 'coastal'
    ORDER BY income DESC
    LIMIT 5
);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim; however, it is yet not working.